# File/Image field not submitting when using Ajax to submit Django form

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, post, django-forms

I'm currently working on a customized admin page on my site where users will be allowed to update their profile page. I have several fields including an image field for profile images... I have then created a **EditProfileForm** to deal with this action. I've learned about serializing the form within the **Ajax** request to post the form data to server side. I have this working for other forms that doesn't have a file field, and it works perfectly. But somehow, it's just not working for this form with the image field.

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['avatar']), label='Change Profile Image')
    mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['mobile']), label='Mobile Number', required=False)
    street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['street']), label='Street', required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['city']), label='City', required=False)
    state = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['state']), label='State', required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['country']), label='Country', required=False)
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs=edit_profile_form_fields['about']), label='About Me', required=False)


    def clean_mobile(self):
        if Account.objects.filter(mobile=self.cleaned_data['mobile']).exists() and len(self.cleaned_data['mobile']) > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Mobile already exists!')

        return self.cleaned_data['mobile']

    def save(self, user_id):
        account = Account.objects.get(user_id=user_id)

        account.avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        account.mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        account.street = self.cleaned_data['street']
        account.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        account.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        account.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        account.about = self.cleaned_data['about']
        account.save()
```

In my html I have...

```
<form id="edit-profile-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="avatar">
            {{ edit_profile_form.avatar.label }}
        </label>
        {{ edit_profile_form.avatar }}
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="mobile">
             {{ edit_profile_form.mobile.label }}
             <span class="mobile-exist text-danger" style="display: none;"></span>
         </label>
         {{ edit_profile_form.mobile }}
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="street">
             {{ edit_profile_form.street.label }}
         </label>
         {{ edit_profile_form.street }}
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="city">
             {{ edit_profile_form.city.label }}
         </label>
         {{ edit_profile_form.city }}
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="country">
             {{ edit_profile_form.country.label }}
         </label>
         {{ edit_profile_form.country }}
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="about">
             {{ edit_profile_form.about.label }}
         </label>
         {{ edit_profile_form.about }}
     </div>

     <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning px-3" id="edit-profile-submit-btn">
              Update Profile <span class="btn-icon-right"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></span>
         </button>

         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-3 ml-3" id="edit-profile-reset-btn">
              Reset <span class="btn-icon-right"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
         </button>

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger px-3 ml-3" id="edit-profile-div-close">
              Cancel <span class="btn-icon-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
         </button>
     </div>
</form>
```

In my js where I do the Ajax call, I have...

```
 var csrfmiddlewaretoken = $("#edit-profile-form").find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
 var form_data = $('#edit-profile-form').serialize();

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/edit-profile/',
     dataType : "json",
     data : {
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfmiddlewaretoken,
         form_data: form_data,
     },
     
     success: function (data){
         console.log('Success');
     },

     error: function (){
         console.log('Error');
     }
 });
```

Now within my views that handles this post request, I have...

```
class EditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/profile.html'
    form_class = EditProfileForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.http import QueryDict  #To basically de-serialize the serialized form passed by the Ajax request

        new_form_data = QueryDict(request.POST['form_data'].encode('ASCII'))

        #From the new form data (QueryDict Obj), I will set a dict.
        data = {
            'avatar': new_form_data.get('avatar'),
            'mobile': new_form_data.get('mobile'),
            'street': new_form_data.get('street'),
            'city': new_form_data.get('city'),
            'state': new_form_data.get('state'),
            'country': new_form_data.get('country'),
            'about': new_form_data.get('about'),
        }

        #Passing data dict as an argument to initialize the form
        form = self.form_class(data)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form is valid')

        else:
            print('Form is not valid')
```

I have tried printing the **data** dict which I have create but **'avatar'** is none. Here's an example...

The form:
[image]

The result from printing the data...
[image]

So even though I have uploaded the image, it has not been passed as part of the form data from the **Ajax** request. I have been researching but yet to find a similar problem that has a solution. Looking forward to getting some help from you wonderful people soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! I used `FormData` to package up the data from my edit profile form then append the **image field** to that `FormData` then submit it. Submitted a bit different from the methods I've used when dealing without files though.

Update in my js...

```
var form = $("#edit-profile-form")[0];
var form_data = new FormData(form);

// Appending the attached file to the form_data to access it from the server side
form_data.append('new_avatar', $("#avatar")[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/edit-profile/',
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function (data){
        console.log('Success');
    },

    error: function (){
       console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

Then in my views, I would just initialize the form in a normal manner without any de-serialization.

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form is valid')

        else:
            print('Form is not valid')

        return JsonResponse(context)
```

This did the job for me... Sweet and nice! :-)